# I am getting finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection warning in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting **finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection** warning in the android studio.Not Sure why I am getting this warning

> 03-18 12:58:58.105 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection 03-18 12:59:01.321 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection 03-18 12:59:05.254 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection 03-18 12:59:10.570 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection 03-18 12:59:20.754 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection 03-18 12:59:33.469 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection 03-18 12:59:36.805 17928-17928/in.uu.physiotherapy
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection